# Documents in local MongoDB database not loading to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am having a problem in MongoDB Atlas, collections are loaded when connecting but the documents are not.

Here is the connection line of code :
`mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin:test123@cluster0.evewv.mongodb.net/hirafidb");`
my local database is populated with data but in MongoDB Atlas here is what I get :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSVSf.png)

Comment: How did you attempt to copy the data from your local DB to Atlas?